# Checking if task in another thread has already finished in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sleep

I'm working on downloading a html source from website and displaying it on TextView. It's being downloaded in another thread and I want to display it when it'll be finished. So. i have to pause main thread until it finish. Right now i do it like this:

```
    MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(this);
    task.execute();
    Thread.sleep(6000);
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(task.result);
```

But as you see it's not the best way to do this. I need something like "sleepUntil(boolean is MyTaskCompleated)". Is there something like this in Java. Or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: If you want sequential execution, perform the task in the main thread...don't introduce multi-threading if you're just going to block the main thread anyway...

Comment: You can never be sure it will take 6sec to complete. Why not have the async task an inner class and in post execute you can set the text?

Comment: I strongly disagree with @user1329572. You should never do network operations in the main thread! Use a progress indicator in a AsynTask is definitely the way to go. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 1):

Having the UI thread sleep is no different than performing the actual work in the UI thread itself. Both cases will end up with a UI that is not responsive, and can cause an "Application Not Responding" message.

It seems like your goal is to not allow the user to perform any other actions while this work is being performed. One alternative approach to do this would be to block the UI with a progress dialog, and `dismiss()` the dialog in the `onPostExecute()` method of your `AsyncTask` subclass.

Answer (score 1):

I use **callbacks**.

*MyCallback.java*

```
public interface MyCallback<T> {
    public void onComplete(T result);
}
```

*MyAsyncTask.java*

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private MyCallback<Boolean> mCallback;

    public MyAsyncTask(MyCallback<Boolean> callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if (mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.onComplete(result); // will call onComplete() on MyActivity once the job is done
        }
    }

}
```

In this example, this callback will take nothing as argument and return a `Boolean`.

Now all you have to do is to let your calling class (`MyActivity` for example) implements `MyCallback`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyCallback<Boolean> {
    // ...

    xxx {
        MyAsyncTask myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(this); // the callback
        myAsyncTask.execute();
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onComplete(Boolean result) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is what I do and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a class that extends Asynctask and then perform your work in the overload methods. This will give you the ability to run your task on another thread and have it execute code after the result is completed.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Look at the example under Usage. The overloads for onPreExecute and onPostExecute run on the UI thread so you can do something like show a progress dialog onPreExecute and dismiss it onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

```
doSomeWork();
new MyAsyncTask().execute(url);
```

The AsyncTask:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {
 protected void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     downloadHtml(urls[0]); 
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     continueWorkHere();
 }
}
```